Error: The method 'markNeedsBuild' isn't defined for the class 'RenderLoadingIndicator' in syncfusion_flutter_charts after upgrading to Flutter 3.2.4
I'm working on a Flutter project where I'm using the syncfusion_flutter_charts package. After upgrading Flutter to version 3.2.4 and updating the syncfusion_flutter_charts package to the latest version (26.2.10), I encountered the following error:

../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/syncfusion_flutter_charts-26.2.10/lib/src/charts/base.dart:3225:7:
Error: The method 'markNeedsBuild' isn't defined for the class
'RenderLoadingIndicator'.


'RenderLoadingIndicator' is from 'package:syncfusion_flutter_charts/src/charts/base.dart' (..

It seems that the markNeedsBuild method is not recognized in the RenderLoadingIndicator class. I haven't made any changes to the code related to this, and I'm not sure why this is happening after the upgrade.
Here are the things I've tried:
Cleaned the project using flutter clean and rebuilt it.
Downgraded to an earlier version of syncfusion_flutter_charts, which doesn't throw this error, but I need the features of the latest version.
Has anyone faced a similar issue or can provide guidance on how to resolve this?

check the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/78883987/11217742

Yes, latest syncfusion_flutter_charts versions are not compatible with current updates of flutter SDK.
So you should use an earlier version of  syncfusion_flutter_charts package to overcome this problem, for me this version was working fine with latest version of flutter SDK:
 syncfusion_flutter_charts: ^22.2.9 

and BTW, syncfusion had added a compatibility section in their documentation referring which version of their package shall work correctly to which of flutter versions: take a look

This isn't a solution either. The charts package API had changed a lot since that version and if you updated to the latest charts before updating Flutter SDK you had to refactor your code to these changes. What they should have done is to set SDK restriction on their package if they are not willing to support the most current Flutter SDK. And waiting 3 months for a package update is way too long...
